# One SQLAlchemy query from 3 tables and display result

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 3 database (below), and I have to write ONE sqlalchemy query that will create an outer join on Users, OrderItems and Products that return the last_name, qty and name from the corresponding tables ?

class OrderItem(Base):
**tablename** = 'order'

```
id = sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
product_id = sa.Column('product_id', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('product.id'))
user_id = sa.Column('user_id', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('user.id'))
qty = sa.Column('qty', sa.Integer)
```

class Product(Base):
**tablename** = 'product'

```
id = sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = sa.Column('name', sa.Text)
price = sa.Column('price', sa.Numeric(14,2))
```

class User(Base):
**tablename** = 'user'

```
id = sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
first_name = sa.Column('first_name', sa.Text)
last_name = sa.Column('last_name', sa.Text)
```

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

```
engine.echo = True

session.add(User(id=42, first_name='John', last_name='Cleese'))
session.ad

d(User(id=43, first_name='Eric', last_name='Idle'))
session.add(User(id=44, first_name='Terry', last_name='Jones'))
session.add(User(id=13, first_name='Graham', last_name='Chapman'))

session.add(Product(id=1, price=Decimal('2.10'), name='Rabbit'))
session.add(Product(id=2, price=Decimal('5.10'), name='Parrot'))

session.add(OrderItem(product_id=1, user_id=42, qty=9))
session.add(OrderItem(product_id=1, user_id=42, qty=2))
session.add(OrderItem(product_id=1, user_id=13, qty=2))
session.add(OrderItem(product_id=2, user_id=13, qty=3))
session.add(Ord

erItem(product_id=2, user_id=13, qty=20))

session.commit()
```

I just write one query

## ONE query

```
for user, order, product in session.query(User, OrderItem, Product). \
    select_from(User).outerjoin(OrderItem).join(Product).all():
    print(user.last_name, order.qty, product.name)
```

which give me result:

Cleese 9 Rabbit
Cleese 2 Rabbit
Chapman 2 Rabbit
Chapman 3 Parrot
Chapman 20 Parrot

I want to write the second one query, with relation, like this:

## The second query

#query = session.query(User, OrderItem, Product)

```
query = session.query(User.last_name, OrderItem.qty, Product.name) \
    .outerjoin(User, OrderItem, OrderItem.user_id == User.id) \
    .outerjoin(Product, User, Product.id == User.id)
```

Can you help me how to change this second query to display result?

Answer (score 0):

I changed query for this:

```
sq1 = session.query(User.last_name, OrderItem.qty, Product.name) \
.outerjoin(OrderItem, OrderItem.user_id == User.id) \
.outerjoin(Product, Product.id == User.id)
```

print(sq1))

And I have got result:

```
SELECT user.last_name AS user_last_name, "order".qty AS order_qty, product.name AS product_name 
FROM user LEFT OUTER JOIN "order" ON "order".user_id = user.id
```